# VBA - printing individual sheets as individual and combined pdf

Tags: vba, printing

```
Dim s As String
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws() As Variant 'dynamic array


If LCase(Sheet76.Range("H7")) = "x" Then
    ReDim ws(1 To 7) 'declare size

    'Select file save location
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .Show

       If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
           strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
       End If
    End With

'to print individually
    For i = 1 To 7
        s = Sheet76.Cells(8 + i, 7).Value
        ws(i) = s
        Sheets(s).Select
        strPath = strPath & "\"
        strFileName = strPath & s & ".pdf"

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strFileName, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    Next

end if
```

I have two questions. The above code is for printing out individual pdfs per worksheet. I'm able to print out 4 of the 7, then it has an error runtime message. What am I doing wrong?

Also, why doesn't this work for printing out multiple worksheets as a single pdf?

```
  sheets(ws).select  
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strFileName, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False`
```

EDIT: I fixed the runtime error; the string value for i=5 didn't tie up with the sheet name. I'm still stuck on how to print the selected worksheets as one combined pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    dim ws() as string        
    For i = 1 To 7
            s = Sheet76.Cells(8 + i, 7).Value
        ws(i) = s
    Next

    Sheets(ws).Select
    strFileName = strPath & "Combined.pdf"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=strFileNamering variable., _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

Solution to printing worksheets as a single combined pdf above. I got it to work by declaring ws() array as st